# How can i fix a 404 error when targeting custom taxonomy slug ?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have defined my new taxonomy like this

```
$args = array(
 'labels'       => $labels,
 'show_tagcloud'    => false,
 'hierarchical'     => true,
 'rewrite'          => array( 'slug' => 'activites', 'hierarchical' => true ),
);
register_taxonomy( 'business_category', 'business', $args );
```

I have no custom rewrite rules. 
this url works :

```
http://mydomain.com/activites/architecture-decoration/
```

calling my taxonomy-business_category.php template.

so i want to reach this url now :

```
http://mydomain.com/activites/
```

but it throws a 404. the purpose (besides having a functional breadcrumb) on this page is to list all my custom category terms. how can i target a page that englobes all categories ?

is it a rewrite conflict or a rewrite missing ?

thank for your further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing missing or broken, this is expected behavior. There is no concept of an archive of taxonomy *terms*, archives contain *posts*. It makes sense if you think about it - the main query always contains some sort of collection of posts, which are output by The Loop, there's no way for that to instead be a collection of terms.

A simple fix is to create a page with slug `activites`, create a [Custom Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) for that page, and [output your taxonomy's terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) within that template.